# Upload blob images from MySql to TableView column

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview, blob

I'm trying to upload pictures stored in my MySQL as type Blob with additional information such as - name, price description and Id, into TableView- From SceneBuilder. This is my class with Getters and Setters:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package products;

import java.sql.Blob;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class showp {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String price;
    public Blob picture;
    public String desc;
    public showp(String id, String name, String price,Blob image, String desc){
        this.id= id;
        this.name= name;
        this.price= price;
        this.picture=image;
        this.desc=desc;
    }
    //Getters
    public String getId(){
    return id;
    }
    public String getName(){
    return name;
    }
    public String getPrice(){
    return price;
    }
    public Blob getPicture(){
    return picture;
    }
    public String getDesc(){
    return desc;
    }
    //Setters
    public void setId(String Id){
    this.id=Id;
    }
    public void setName(String Name){
    this.name=Name;
    }
    public void setPrice(String Price){
    this.price=Price;
    }
    public void setPicture(Blob Picture){
    this.picture=Picture;
    }
    public void setDesc(String Desc){
    this.desc=Desc;
    }
}
```

and this is the class, where i populate the table with the data:

```
 public void loadProducts() throws ClassNotFoundException{



      try {
            dc=new DbConncetion();
            Connection conn= dc.Connect();
            ol1=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ol1.clear();
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `products`");
            while(rs.next()){
                ol1.add(new showp(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3), rs.getBlob(4) , rs.getString(5)));
            }
            pName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
            priceP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
                picP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("image"));
            pView.setItems(null);
            pView.setItems(ol1);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


  }
```

I saw many examples here and in the youtube, but i cant understand nothing. Can anyone explain me how to do that. When i execute that code in my table shows name, price and Blob-column in this format `com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@1b8f8da0`. I just want instead of that `com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@1b8f8da0`, to be show the real images in imageview or something else. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. Try following this: https://blogs.oracle.com/javajungle/entry/how_to_pretty_up_your.   I would first recreate this as is. Then alter it for you purposes.

Comment: How to replace the MTweet and MUser in my case? What i should write there?

Comment: Here is an example you  can try to follow. I suggest you do a separate project with an array of image files. Once you mastered that then move to getting image from db. Your focus is albumArt.setCellFacotry. https://github.com/sedj601/ImageInTableColumn/tree/master/src/imageintablecolumn